# Switching between integrated terminals on vscode (mongo/cmd/bash)

Tags: bash, mongodb, shell, visual-studio-code

I have 3 different shells inside VSCODE and want to switch between these. Currently only mongo pops up with "ctrl + ` " and want to switch between the shells.. Is there anyway to do this?

```
    "terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\Windows\\SysWOW64\\cmd.exe",
    "terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Git\\bin\\bash.exe",
    "terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\Program Files\\mongodb\\server\\3.6\\bin\\mongo.exe",
```